# best relationship for this design?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, mysql-workbench

There is a table `users` with autoincrement primary key `id`.

There is also a table `employees` (every employee is a user but not vice versa). The `employees` primary key is `userid`. The field `userid` is not autoincrement.

`employees.userid` should be a foreign key for `users.id`.

Which kind of relationship in Workbench it should be?

As far as I understand:

- It cannot be 1:1 relationships because for a given user the corresponding employee may not exist.
- It is not advisable to be 1:n relationship because n can be only 0 or 1.
- It should be an identifying relation because a user is determined by an employee.

Please advise me what is the best relationship in this case.

Comment: It is an **identifying relation** because an Employee cannot exist in the absence of a corresponding Person. It will also be a (0,1) to 1 relationship, as you described.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best that you learned about relationship types without using an IDE.

If every employee *is* a user, then it should be a straight 1:1 relationship.

If every employee *is not* a user, then you should not be using `userid` as the primary key. Rather, create a surrogate primary key for the employee and make `userid` a nullable foreign key.